# Nested system properties in Java command line

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, system-properties

Is there a way to nest system properties in a Java command line? For instance, specifying something like:

`java -DworkingDir=/tmp -DconfigFile=${workingDir}/someFile.config`.

I aim to use something like that for the Tomcat launch configuration in Eclipse (Tomcat patched to log with SLF4J/Logback) :

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\data\workspaces\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" 
-Dlogback.configurationFile="${catalina.base}\conf\logback.groovy"`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the expansion to happen transparently ... in Java.  But you could do this:

```
$ workingDir=/tmp
$ java -DworkingDir=${workingDir} -DconfigFile=${workingDir}/someFile.config.
```

In other words, get the shell to do the expansion before invoking Java.  (The syntax in a Windows batch file would be different ... but the idea is the same.)

---

Incidentally, if you run a command like this:

```
$ java -DworkingDir=/tmp -DconfigFile=${workingDir}/someFile.config
```

a POSIX shell will interpret `${workingDir}` as a shell variable expansion.  If no `workingDir` variable is defined, this expands to nothing ... so you would need to use quoting to get the `${workingDir}` into the actual Java property value; e.g.

```
$ java -DworkingDir=/tmp -DconfigFile=\${workingDir}/someFile.config
```

Comment: +1. This falls squarely in the shell's bailiwick. Although the asker is evidently using Windows (note the path starting `C:\`), so i assume he will have to use batch script's version of variables and substitution.

Comment: So no way of getting a natural expansion without tricks. Would not work for my expected usage (expansion in a Eclipse launch config). Thanks your answers, both Stephen C and iccthedral responses are acceptable ones and Tom Anderson comment is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just make sure you read and replace it correctly, so for example:

`java -DworkingDir="/tmp" -DconfigFile="${workingDir}/someFile.config"`

```
Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
String wDir = props.getProperty("workingDir");
String configFile = props.getProperty("configFile").replace("${workingDir}", wDir);
System.out.println(configFile);
```

you get the idea...